# Buildfire: Remove Saving Popup

Tags: buildfire

Is there any way to disable the popup that says "saving" when saving to the datastore or publicData database? It's placement is interfering with something on my page.

Here is a screenshot of the popup:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what this pop-up looks like or provide a screenshot? I don't believe I've seen it before.

Comment: @attila226 please check the updated post

Answer (score 0):

I don't see this behavior in other plugins ... I checked a few plugins just now and the message is not displayed. Are you sure it's not something on your side of things?

Comment: Yes. I can see it has a CSS property of "dead-toast". I can't inspect it for too long because it disappears. It happens when working inside of the app.buildfire and I believe on mobile as well

Comment: @user2465134 I see what you mean ... interestingly enough I have never seen this UI myself. Are you seeing this in the SDK/Plugin Tester?

Comment: I believe it's on the phone buildfire previewer and when I am viewing apps on app.buildfire in the widget area. I don't see it on my local version.

Comment: @user2465134 It's odd because I've used many plugins and have never seen the toast. It's possible in the future the SDK will be modified to specify this as a configurable option.

Comment: @user2465134 I believe the toast is now turned off by default.

Comment: I pulled the latest SDK and I still see toast

Comment: @user2465134 I believe at the moment it's only in live apps.